# jQuery: Show content of the <p> beyond one line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 paragraphs, as shown in the HTML below. I want the content of p-show to not exceed beyond the first line normally. And when the "Show me" button of each respective p-show is clicked, it should expand and show all of the content inside it.

I tried the below JavaScript but it doesn't seem to work:

```js
var h = $('p-show')[0].scrollHeight;


$('.p-show a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.p-show').animate({
        'height': h
    })
});

$(document).click(function() {
    $('.p-show').animate({
        'height': '50px'
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="p-show p-show1">
Content Content Content <br />
Content Content Content <br />
Content Content Content <br />
Content COntent Content
<a href="#" class="show-me show-me1">Show Me</a>
</p>

<p class="p-show p-show2">
Content Content Content <br />
Content Content Content <br />
Content Content Content <br />
Content COntent Content
<a href="#" class="show-me show-me2">Show Me</a>
</p>

<p class="p-show p-show3">
Content Content Content <br />
Content Content Content <br />
Content Content Content <br />
Content COntent Content
<a href="#" class="show-me show-me3">Show Me</a>
</p>
```

Comment: I dont really know, but to achive this, the `<a>` should be placed outside the p.show..

Comment: Strongly recommend wrapping the content in `div`s rather than using `br`. Amongst other things, it makes doing what you're asking about easier: Just show/hide the divs.

Comment: this does not work because you got event handling wrong. See post below for the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```js
$(document).on('click', '.p-show + a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).prev('p').toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

```css
.p-show {
   height:1em; overflow: hidden;
}
.p-show.expanded {
   height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="p-show p-show1">
Content Content Content <br />
Content Content Content <br />
Content Content Content <br />
Content COntent Content

</p>
<a href="#" class="show-me show-me1">Show Me</a>

<p class="p-show p-show2">
Content Content Content <br />
Content Content Content <br />
Content Content Content <br />
Content COntent Content

</p>
<a href="#" class="show-me show-me2">Show Me</a>
```

Comment: this looks like an interesting method. instead of toggleClass i would suggest using addClass, and if using toggleClass we should change the text of Show Me to Hide Me when it is toggled. If using addClass we should hide the .show me after .p-show has the class expanded added on it. 

something like ".p-show.expanded+a {display: none;}"

Comment: @AlexZahir, Toni nailed it :) .

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can have the content that can be hidden and shown wrapped in a  element with a class assigned to it so that it can be accessed with jQuery

**Example:**

HTML

```
<p class="p-show p-show1">
Content Content Content <br />
   <span class="more">
   Content Content Content <br />
   Content Content Content <br />
   Content COntent Content
   </span>
<a href="#" class="show-me show-me1">Show Me</a>
</p>
```

CSS

```
.more{
   display:none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(".show-me").click(function(){
   $(this).prev(".more").slideToggle();
});
```